# What should I say if I am not drunk but I feel that my head is heavy?

Tags: word-choice

Imagine you had several beers, you are not yet drunk but you feel that your head is heavy, you know, feel good. Is there any specific word for that?

Comment: I recommend NOT saying, "Offisher, offisher, waymint now, I'm not, I'm not drunk, okay? but I could really ushum help holding up my head."

Comment: Forty years ago, the standard U.S. college term for this state was "a slight buzz."

Comment: "dizzy" maybe? Although I know it may not exactly refer to "heaviness". "feeling unable to stand steadily, for example because you are looking down from a high place or because you are ill" is what Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says for the word dizzy.

Comment: @Neeku that's what I usually use, I thought that maybe there is a better word for it. Thanks!

Comment: “What should I say if I am not drunk but I feel that my head is heavy?” — One thing, and one thing only. “Another beer please, good sir.”

Comment: @SvenYargs *Buzz* is still in use in the US. A common cautionary advertisement warns that *[Buzzed driving is drunk driving*](http://buzzeddriving.adcouncil.org/)

Comment: The specific word for someone who has had several beers and is making a point to deny that they are drunk is "drunk" ;-) But it's an irregular formation: "I am fine to drive", "you are drunk", "he is paralytic", all refer to the same level of drunkenness.

Comment: I'd say "I need another one"

Comment: I usually go with 'merry'. If I was told someone was 'tipsy' I'd expect them to be pretty drunk. Whereas if I was told someone was 'merry', I'd expect them to be slightly drunk, but not very.

Comment: http://buzzeddriving.adcouncil.org/

Comment: In Sweden we have a nice word that translates "Lounge drunk" (Salongsberusad) , it means that you feel the slight warmth and feel good of the alcohol but still can behave and act as not beeing drunk.

Comment: @AmirMasoud Yep. I edited my answer yesterday to provide further detail, by the way. (:

Comment: Not drunk yet? Sláinte!

Comment: Do you mean American drunk or Irish drunk?

Comment: 1 is enough, 2 is too many, 3 is nowhere near enough...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In British English this early level of inebriation is known as being ***[tipsy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tipsy?q=tipsy)***:

> Slightly drunk: *tipsy revellers*

Obviously its onset will vary across individuals, but in my personal experience the condition of tipsiness prevails in the two-to-four pint range. You're not drunk, but you've got that buzz, you're feeling merry and conversation is at its height of lucidity: the inhibition of sobriety is gone, but nobody's slurring their speech yet.

Comment: +1 _Tipsy_ is the point where you have the choice to control your drinking or allow the drink to control you. After _tipsy_ the beer takes over and you no longer have the ability to determine if you should have another pint or not. The answer to that question is always _yes_. Only the complete inability to speak, nod or raise your hand will prevent you from getting one more in.

Comment: Thanks, then I think I can use a combination of tipsy and dizzy. I like **tipsiness**.

Comment: @AmirMasoud I like tipsiness too :)

Comment: There is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_and_emotional

Comment: This is the same in American English.  "Sober" -> "Tipsy" -> "Inebriated" -> "Drunk" -> "Smashed" is the approximate scale of alcohol.

Comment: @Joe In Australian English we have more fine-grained levels of drunkenness: "Sober" -> "Tipsy" -> "Pissed" -> "Drunk" -> "Smashed" -> "Blind/Maggot/Blotto/Off his chops".

Comment: Yeah, American english is quite deficient in describing levels of drunkenness.  Probably due to lower tolerance levels over here thanks to prohibition ;)

Comment: I think the Scandinavian scale is something like ‘Boring’ -> ‘Tipsy’ -> ‘Getting there’ -> ‘Inebriated’ -> ‘Drunk’ -> ‘Pissed’ -> ‘Off your head’ -> ‘Falling over’ -> ‘Stomach pump’ -> ‘Should have had your stomach pumped’ -> ‘Dead’.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to tipsy, the word "buzzed" also comes to mind. Might be an American thing.

More generally, you should consult a thesaurus for synonyms of the word "drunk". I'm sure there are plenty of options to choose from.

Comment: To me, "buzzed" conveys that slightly warm, merry feeling you get in this state better than "tipsy", which sounds more like you are so drunk you are about to tip over.

Comment: +1 because buzzed (where I come from) frequently is used to describe that "feel good" feeling that the OP specifically mentions.

Answer (score 7):

> ***Light-headed***: Unable to think clearly or move steadily, for example during a fever or after drinking alcohol.  Synonym: dizzy. e.g. The
>   sun and the wine had made him a little light-headed.
>   ... say Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightheadedness) also has a nice article about it, in addition to [***dizziness***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dizziness) and [***presyncope***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presyncope).

However I think *light-headedness* would be the closest to what you mean, and it's hilarious to see they call it *lightness* in English where the same feeling in another language would be called *heaviness*!

Another word that might be better to use than light-headedness, is *tipsiness*.

**tipsy:** slightly drunk. [LDOCE].
**tipsy:** The state when you are drinking alchohol in which you are past light headedness but before being drunk. [TheUrbanDictionary]

Comment: Quite funny (at least from my (non-native speaker) point of view) to see that the question mentions "head is heavy" yet the answer is "light_headed".

Comment: that is funny indeed!

Comment: Funny but true eh!

Comment: To me at least, light-headed is more like how you feel when you're ill, or when you haven't had enough to eat.  It's not a pleasant feeling and I wouldn't describe mild drunkenness this way.

Comment: @Nathan Interesting. I would think of the feeling you get when you're ill as having a _heavy head_, whereas the giddiness that comes with light intoxication I would definitely think of as _light-headedness_; in other words, the exact opposite of your associations.

Answer (score 5):

I think of

[Mellow](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mellow) INFORMAL Relaxed and cheerful through being slightly drunk:

> everybody got very mellow and slept well

Answer (score 3):

As well as "tipsy", we sometimes say *merry* in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers here, older words would include Tipsy, and Mellow, with the latter being not uncommon in Canada, though more so in the 70s and 80s. Mildly inebriated would be technical, and tipsy might not go down well in an all-male group. I wonder what a truly 2000s phrase would be?

Answer (score 0):

For me the description of a heavy head is more of a tired feeling than that of being light-headed or tipsy.  I'd probably say "Groggy" would be a stronger fit.

> **groggy**: dazed, weak, or unsteady, especially from illness, intoxication, sleep, or a blow.

Comment: I would have used groggy for the feeling during a light hangover, so more related to "tired and slightly ill".